# Textbox sizes displaying wrong in VS 2017

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I am using VS 2017 and just making a simple app with a few textboxes. I created a blank project for UWP.

I've added four text boxes and this is what it looks like in VS in the designer. [image: Visual Studio App Designer]

But when it runs it either looks like this[image]

or like this?
[image]

Can anyone explain why this is occurring? All the text boxes are set to 23 Height and 120 Width. All the same settings.

I've done edits in the CS code rather than using the XAML editor

Here is my code. All I've done is change the height, width and position.

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <TextBox x:Name="digitEntryBoxDec" 
             TextChanged="digitEntryBoxDec_TextChanged" 
             MouseLeftButtonUp="digitEntryBoxDec_MouseLeftButtonUp" 
             KeyDown="digitEntryBoxDec_KeyDown" 
             Height="23"
             Width="120" Margin="262,32,261.2,365"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="digitEntryBoxHex" 
             TextChanged="digitEntryBoxHex_TextChanged" 
             Height="23" 
             Width="120" Margin="262,60,261.2,337"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="digitEntryBoxBin" 
             TextChanged="digitEntryBoxBin_TextChanged" 
             Height="23" 
             Width="120" Margin="262,88,261.2,309"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" 
             Height="23" 
             Width="120" Margin="262,116,261.2,281"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="colouringBox" 
               Fill="#FFF4F4F5" 
               Height="80" 
               Width="80" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: It seems some control is hide on the `TextBox` or the `Witdth` of `TextBox` is larger than the width of Panel. You should be able post your XAML code that can help us analyze and diagnose this issue.

Comment: @JaydenGu-MSFT I've removed the margins and reworked it to be aligned to the left and only use margin direction and it seems to have worked

Comment: When the ActualWidth of the Page is 500, the TextBox can not be seems with your code. If you want your TextBox in the center of the Page, you can put then in the `StackPanel` and set `Center` to the `HorizontalAlignment` of the `StackPanel`.